# Illegal sequential statement error

Tags: vhdl, sequential, dataflow, shift-register

please can anyone tell me how to fix this code?

what is the Illegal_sequential_statement error(in modelSim)?

why it say that near when nead ';' (in quartus) ?

```
LIBRARY ieee ;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY Shift_reg IS
PORT( Par_LD: IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
      Serial_In: IN std_logic;
      Serial_Out:OUT std_logic;
      RST, LD, EN, CLK: IN std_logic);
END Shift_reg;


ARCHITECTURE shiftRegARCH OF Shift_reg IS 

SIGNAL TEMP_REG : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL TEMP_SOUT : STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN

process(CLK,RST)
  BEGIN 

    TEMP_REG <= (OTHERS => '0') WHEN (RST = '1') ELSE 
                 Par_LD WHEN (EN = '0' AND LD = '1')ELSE
                (Serial_In & TEMP_REG(7 DOWNTO 1)) WHEN (EN = '1')ELSE
                TEMP_REG ;                
    TEMP_SOUT <= TEMP_REG(0) WHEN (EN = '1') ELSE TEMP_SOUT;
    Serial_Out <= TEMP_SOUT;
  END PROCESS;


END shiftRegARCH ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditional signal assignment

```
    TEMP_REG <= (OTHERS => '0') WHEN (RST = '1') ELSE
             Par_LD WHEN (EN = '0' AND LD = '1')ELSE
            (Serial_In & TEMP_REG(7 DOWNTO 1)) WHEN (EN = '1')ELSE
            TEMP_REG ;
```

is only valid with VHDL 2008. You probably have your compiler settings set to VHDL 2002 or VHDL 93

Comment: It's valid in other VHDL editions too ... but only outside a process.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to lasplund noting that a sequential conditional signal assignment is only supported in VHDL -2008 compliant tools which can sometimes be cured with tool configuration or command line arguments, you are not using a recognized construct to indication sequential (clocked) hardware.

Synthesis doesn't interpret the presence of `CLK` in the sensitivity list as inferring clocked storage, and there will like be both rising edge and falling edge events on `CLK`.

This pretty much says you should use an equivalent if statement with a recognized form to infer clocked hardware:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shift_reg is
    port ( 
        par_ld:     in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        serial_in:  in  std_logic;
        serial_out: out std_logic;
        rst, ld, 
        en, clk:    in  std_logic
    );
end entity shift_reg;


architecture shiftregarch of shift_reg is 
    signal temp_reg:    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    -- signal temp_sout:   std_logic;
begin

    process(clk,rst)
    begin 
        -- temp_reg <= (others => '0') when (rst = '1') else
        --              par_ld         when (en = '0' and ld = '1') else
        --             serial_in & temp_reg(7 downto 1)
        --                             when (en = '1');
        --    --         temp_reg ;   
        if  rst = '1' then
            temp_reg <= (others => '0');
            serial_out <= '0';
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if en = '0' and ld = '1' then
                temp_reg <= par_ld;
            elsif en = '1' then
                temp_reg <= serial_in & temp_reg( 7 downto 1);
                serial_out <= temp_reg(0);
            end if;
        end if;

        -- temp_sout <= temp_reg(0) when (en = '1') else temp_sout;
        -- serial_out <= temp_sout;
    end process;
end architecture shiftregarch;
```

Note the lack of final `else`s which are redundant in sequential storage, as well as throwing out `temp_sout` as not needed and resetting `serial_out` and including it in the `en` umbrella.

There's a section in one of the Quartus II manuals entitled **Recommended HDL Coding Styles** displaying Altera's recommendation for expressing clocked logic. It's not all inclusive as the now withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 gives several other forms.

It contains several shift register examples and discusses default values and secondary controls.

The method shown with the rising_edge function is found in 1076.6.

While Lars addressed your immediate error it's likely you would have encountered additional errors.